# cant set headers after they are set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, neo4j

Im trying to get the idsFromMongo I saved in my neo4j database and search for those ids in the mongodb to return the objects I want. It works 1 time but then my server crashes and it returns the error Can't set headers after they are sent.

This is my code:.

```
routes.get('/advertisements/recommended/:brand', function(req, res) {
  res.contentType('application/json');

  var brandFromUrl = req.params.brand;
  var advertisementIds = [];

  Advertisement.find({'car.brand': brandFromUrl})
    .then(function (ads) {
      // res.status(200).json(ads);
      ads.forEach(function (record) {
        console.log('ids: ' + record._id)
        session
          .run("MERGE(a:Advertisement {idFromMongo: {idParam}, brand: {brandParam}}) WITH a MATCH(b: Advertisement {brand: {brandParam}}) MERGE(a)-[:SHARED_BRAND]->(b)", {idParam: record._id.toString(), brandParam: brandFromUrl})
          .then(function(result) {
            session
              .run("MATCH (n:Advertisement{brand: {brandParam}}) RETURN (n)", {brandParam: brandFromUrl})
              .then(function(result) {
                result.records.forEach(function(record){
                  advertisementIds.push(record._fields[0].properties.idFromMongo);
                });
                Advertisement.find({
                  '_id': { $in: advertisementIds}
                }, function(err, docs){
                  res.status(200).json(docs);
                })
            })
        })
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

This is my error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\api\advertisement.routes.v1.js:70:35
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4046:16)
    at c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\kareem\index.js:273:21
    at c:\dev\individueel-project\individueel-database\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: You can send response only once per request. But in your code, you are sending  multiple response inside for statement

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are executing an array and into the array you are sending the response. So, eventually it will send the responde several times, but only first time will work, after that it will raise an error.
To solve it, you should answer the request after the all promises into array has finished (Promise.all) or if you don't need to wait until the whole array has finished, check if you have already responded and don't do it again.